# Joomla 3 Blank screen Admin Login

Tags: php, joomla

When I type in **www.website.com/administrator** on my Joomla site I get a blank page. Nowhere to input login info. But when I type in **www.website.com/administrator/index.php**, I get the login page. Anyone know how to fix this?

Some site details:

- PHP Version   5.3.23
- Web Server    Apache
- Joomla! Version   Joomla! 3.0.3

  Stable

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have index.html page in your administrator directory. remove it and it will display the index.php page. index.html will take precedence unless otherwise specified in your server settings.

Comment: Oh my.. silly of me for not checking! That was the solution! Thanks for the quick response!